# Existe alguma chamada de sistema pra ler apenas uma linha de arquivo em assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly

Tipo o fget do c, que manda pra uma variavel todos os caracteres da linha entre o o inicio dela e o caractere carriage return

Answer (score 2):

depende do sistema, no caso as chamadas de sistema ou syscall normalmente estão vinculadas a um determinado sistema operacional e não necessarimente a uma arquitetura como x86 (depedendo as vezes sim kkk), veja por exemplo o syscall open (5) e read (4) do int80 no sistema linux, voce consegue ler uma quantidade de bytes em um arquivo por ele, com isso é possivel criar um fgets generico (voce pode ler byte por byte ate achar o caracter de quebra de linha seria uma alternativa)

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
mov eax,5 ;syscall open
mov ebx,arq ;stackoverflow.txt
mov ecx,0  ;r
mov edx,0  ;permissão 000
int 0x80

mov [descritor],eax

repetir:
mov ebx,[descritor] ;move o descritor para ebx
mov eax,0x3 ;syscall do read 
mov ecx,kodo;joga na variavel kodo
mov edx,0x1 ;ler 1bytes do arquivo
int 0x80

mov ebx,1 ;descritor stdout
mov eax,0x4 ;syscall do write 
mov ecx,kodo;joga na variavel kodo
mov edx,0x1 ;ler 1bytes do arquivo
int 0x80

mov edx,[kodo] ;ler o endereço onde foi armazenado
cmp edx,0xa ;se for igual 0xa
je sair ;pula para sair

jmp repetir ; se nao volta a repetir

sair:
mov eax,0x1 ;syscall do exit
mov ebx,0x0
int 0x80

section .data
arq: db "stackoverflow.txt"

section .bss
kodo: resb 200
descritor: resb 4
```

voce tambem pode usar as API do libc, com isso é possivel usar as funções fgets, printf, scanf e etc, veja um exemplo abrindo um arquivo com o fopen lendo com fgetc e exibindo com o putchar

```
;nasm -f elf kodo.asm -o kodo.o
;gcc kodo.o -o kodo.out

global main
extern putchar
extern fgetc
extern fopen
extern exit

section .text

main:

push arq_tipo
push arq
call fopen

push eax ;esse é o descriot passado pelo fopen
call fgetc

push eax ;joga o retorno do getc na pilha
call putchar

push 0x0
call exit

section .data
arq: db "stackoverflow.txt",0x0
arq_tipo: db "r",0x0
```

sem dizer que muitas funções como fgets são criadas por chamadas mais baixas como o read e algumas outras, tanto que se voce olhar no strace na parte que ele chama o fgets e putchar vai perceber que são open, read e write

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]